# Using "the" before "most"

Tags: word-usage, definite-article, possessives

Consider these two sentences:

> 1) It is powerful enough to cover most scenarios of content extraction.
>
> 2) It is powerful enough to cover **the** most scenarios. (or better *the most possible scenarios*).

I think in the sentence 2, as I cut the rest of the sentence, I can use "the" to restrict the ***scenarios*** to the context of the sentence.

Is my analysis of using "the" here, is creditable?

Comment: I think it should be, ". .  . to cover most of **the** scenarios." (to refer to the scenarios according to the context). By saying "the most. . ." I think it is in need of an adjective (considering the superlative construction -> "The most possible scenario(s)")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***The* most** would mean "more than any other similar tool".

**This car gets the most miles per gallon of all cars in its class.**

**Most** would refer to "the majority".

**In a desert, most days it does not rain.**

So you'd want to say:

> It is powerful enough to cover most scenarios.

i.e. "the majority of scenarios"